# WPF Using Extended Toolkit Wizard - How to hide footer area?

Tags: wpf, footer, wizard, wpf-extended-toolkit

I am using Extended Toolkit to create a wizard in WPF.

I choose `PageType = WizardPageType.Blank`.

I want to see an empty page, but I still see the footer area (I hide all buttons).

How can I hide this footer area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no property to hide the footer area.

However, you can override the control template of the wizard. FYI, the default style is available [on GitHub](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/blob/master/ExtendedWPFToolkitSolution/Src/Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit/Wizard/Themes/Generic.xaml).

Assuming the namespace `xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"`, your "very basic" control template could look like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type xctk:Wizard}">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type xctk:Wizard}">
        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
              BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
              BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
              Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
          <Grid>
            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding CurrentPage, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
          </Grid>
        </Border>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

Place this into `Window.Resources` or `Application.Resources` or wherever you like.